# How to set in pandas the first column and row as index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I read in a CSV, I can say `pd.read_csv('my.csv', index_col=3)` and it sets the third column as index.

How can I do the same if I have a pandas dataframe in memory? And how can I say to use the first row also as an index? The first column and row are strings, rest of the matrix is integer.

Comment: Sorry are you after `set_index`? this will set a column as the index for a row you'd have to override the index directly `df.index = df.iloc[0].values` note that the row length would need to match the current number of rows in your df

Comment: Thank you EdChum, your answer helped me a lot. In my case it was not df.index, it was df.columns. And for the rows I needed to use set_index. Thank you.

Comment: @Oli Might be worth leaving an answer, since you haven't accepted any of the current answers?

Answer (score 107):

You can try this regardless of the number of rows

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
```

Comment: This is actually the easiest solution.

Comment: Agreed, this is the best solution when using CSV files

Comment: The question already mentions this and specifically asks for in memory DataFrames.

Answer (score 39):

Making the first (or n-th) column the index in increasing order of verboseness:

```
df.set_index(list(df)[0])
df.set_index(df.columns[0])
df.set_index(df.columns.tolist()[0])
```

Making the first (or n-th) row the index:

```
df.set_index(df.iloc[0].values)
```

You can use both if you want a multi-level index:

```
df.set_index([df.iloc[0], df.columns[0]])
```

Observe that using a column as index will automatically drop it as column. Using a row as index is just a copy operation and won't drop the row from the DataFrame.

Comment: Suppose I have a DataFrame in memory (don't want to read it in again) and the column I want to set as the index is "Unnamed: 0", an old unnamed index from an exported DataFrame of another session. Do you know of a way to set the index to the "Unnamed: 0" column _but also_ remove the name of the index?

Answer (score 28):

Maybe try set_index()?

```
df = df.set_index([2])
```

Comment: `set_index` expects column labels. This will raise `KeyError` if your 3rd column has a name.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: If the column has a non-numerical index, you have to replace the number with the said non-numerical index, e.g., df = df.set_index(['two']).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `df = pd.read_csv(header = 0)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).